# jQuery DataTables plugin fixed header being overwritten

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I've a table of data that uses the DataTable plugin. I've fixed the header, search box and page listing in place and this works fine. The table headers are offset from a fixed header.

The data for the table is loaded with Ajax and the DataTable set up like this;

```
table = $("#data-table").DataTable({
        dom: '<"dom_wrapper"fl>tip',            
        iDisplayLength: 100,
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],

        columnDefs: [
            { targets: [3, 4], orderable: false }
        ],            
        order: [[1, 'asc']]            
    });
```

The header offset is set up like this;

```
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table, {
        header: true,            
        headerOffset: 195
    });
```

I've styled the dom_wrapper and associated controls like this;

```
div.dom_wrapper {
position: sticky;
top: 160px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
margin-bottom: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
}

div.dataTables_length {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
width: 50%;
overflow: hidden;    
}

div.dataTables_filter {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
width: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

The controls and table header are correctly fixed in position. The problem I'm having is that the contents of the table are still visible in front of and above the controls above the table header as below;

[image: dodgy display!]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so with some fiddling about I've pretty much sorted this. It was a case of sorting out the css - I've implemented this in the 'always' function after the ajax call.

```
 //enable sticky header
    $('div.dom_wrapper').css({
        'position': 'sticky',
        'top': '154px',
        'background': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
        'padding-bottom': '30px',
        'margin-bottom': '44px'
    });

    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table, {
        header: true,
        headerOffset: 184
    });
```

The fancy switches still render on top of the search box but using simple checkboxes fixes the issue so I just need to identify the styles causing this in the switches

Comment: z-index : 1 on the dom_wrapper. Obvious really.